# I don't know why I'm getting "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" error

Tags: python, web-scraping, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a tracker program and use BeautifulSoup and requests libraries to scrape the price off of Steam websites. Then write those price values into an excel file using openpyxl.

Everything worked flawlessly in the first four game titles. The error exists as I try to add more game titles into the list.

*See the code below*

After I added Hollow Knight item into the wistlist array, I started to get this error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Even though I'm not using any comparison sign to compare values in this program.

Side note:
I have json file that stored the next line of where to put the values into the excel. And the program will update the line values by 1 after it finished executing all the codes above it. See the function updateTrackingLines() below

```py
cookies = {'birthtime': '568022401'} # For Steam's age verification

wishlist = [
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/477160/Human_Fall_Flat/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/242760/The_Forest/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/4000/Garrys_Mod/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/367520/Hollow_Knight/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/588650/Dead_Cells/s",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/320240/We_Happy_Few/", "https://store.steampowered.com/app/589510/Shovel_Knight_Specter_of_Torment/",
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/413150/Stardew_Valley/"
]
l = len(wishlist)
def updateProducts():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\Python37\SteamTracker\ProductsTracker.xlsx")
    sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
    today = date.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    lines = getTrackingLines()
    for i in range(0,l):
        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheets[i])
        html = requests.get(wishlist[i],cookies=cookies)
        page_soup = soup(html.content, "html.parser")
        price = page_soup.find("div",{"class":"game_purchase_price price"}).text.strip()
        price = price[1:len(price)]
        sheet.cell(lines[i],2, value = float(price)) # updating cells
        sheet.cell(lines[i],1, value = today)
        print("successed updating " + sheet.title)
    wb.save("C:\Python37\SteamTracker\ProductsTracker.xlsx")
    updateTrackingLines() # See explaination of this func above
```

Full traceback

```
PS C:\Python37\SteamTracker> & C:/Users/Han/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py
c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py:48: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
  sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py:53: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheets[i])
successed updating Human Fall Flat
successed updating The Forest
successed updating Garry's Mod
successed updating GTA V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py", line 75, in <module>
    updateProducts()
  File "c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py", line 58, in updateProducts
    sheet.cell(lines[i],2, value = float(price)) # updating cells
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 236, in cell
    if row < 1 or column < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: Updated full traceback above.

Comment: You may not use any comparison, but as you can see in the traceback, openpyxl is using a comparison as an extra check, which is causing your error.

Comment: obviously `lines[i]` is a `str`, but we cannot see for sure from what you post here.

Comment: `lines[i]` will be a string, which you can't use for the column number; make sure it is a proper integer that can be used as column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error stated, `<` was used to compare `str` to `int`.

```
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 236, in cell
    if row < 1 or column < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

From the line of the code

```
    if row < 1 or column < 1:
```

it seems you passed `str` as either `row` or `column`. while look into your code, `lines[i]` might be the one that is `str`.

```
  File "c:/Python37/SteamTracker/main.py", line 58, in updateProducts
    sheet.cell(lines[i],2, value = float(price)) # updating cells
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Looks like I create a tiny daunting mistake here with the json file here I have with.

When I added additional items onto my json, I accidentally coded the value lines as str type instead of just plain int.

And we need an int value to locate the cells in excel sheet, but the code value lines of mine are str type.

I better learn to watch for typo.

Thanks for your help and participation in this thread

```
{
  "titles": [
    {
      "name": "Human Fall Flat",
      "line": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "The Forest",
      "line": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Garry's Mod",
      "line": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Grand Theft Auto V",
      "line": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Hollow Knight",
      "line": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dead Cells",
      "line": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "We Happy Few",
      "line": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Shovel Knight: Specter of Torment",
      "line": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Stardew Valley",
      "line": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```